# git automatically squash commits to previous commits that changed the same file/s

Tags: git, squash

I have a feature branch with interleaved series of commits involving different files.  I'd like to squash the commits together that involved the same files, but not squash together series of commits that don't touch each other.  I don't want to have to do manual inspection of the changes from each commit to determine this.

If for example there are these commits:

1. change files A and B
2. changes C
3. changes A
4. changes C
5. changes C and D
6. changes A and C

The rebase would automatically

- Squash 3 onto 1
- Squash 4 onto 2
- Don't squash 5 onto 2
- Don't squash 6 onto 1 or 2 (but later changes to A and/or C would get squashed onto 6).

Possibly after this there is some breakage- maybe some changes depended on those other changes in separate files and are now out of order, but I would have fewer commits to examine and fewer tests to run if I did want every single commit to work (and possibly I end up manually squashing everything together in the end).

Is an elaborate script that parses lists of changed files required here?

Comment: Yes, you will need to write your own script to do this.

Answer (score 3):

## Git Absorb

`git absorb` is a git extension for a related purpose. It distributes all changes in the staging area onto previous commits.

### Example

In the question the following example is given. I have modified it.

Commits:

1. change files A and B
2. changes C
3. changes D and A

Next, you make modifications to A, B, C and D.

```sh
git add A B C D
git absorb --and-rebase
```

- The changes to A will be moved to the first commit (or the third commit depending on the exact changes).
- The changes to B will be moved to the first commit.
- The changes to C --> second commit.
- D --> third commit.

### Further Links

Documentation: https://crates.io/crates/git-absorb
Source code: https://github.com/tummychow/git-absorb

Comment: I could unroll commits so changes are staged again, and do a big git absorb on the changes of what used to be multiple commits, or maybe sequential git absorbs, undoing 1 commit at a time.

Answer (score 1):

### `git rebase -i` makes this incredibly easy.

It seems like a lot of steps below, but that is only because I am walking you through it in detail so you understand how it works, and added some steps for safety.

1. Checkout the branch you want to do this on.
2. [Optional] `git checkout -b <tmp-branch-name>` to do this work on a temporary branch. This makes it easy to compare the re-ordered and squashed branch with the original to make sure you haven't lost any changes.
3. Determine a ref to the ***parent*** of the earliest commit you want to re-order/squash. In your given example `head~6` should work but use any valid ref such as `<hash>`, `<hash>^`, `some-tag^`.
4. `git rebase -i <the ref from step 3>
5. This will generate a rebase `todo` script (essentially a high-level rebase script). It will be opened in your editor. It will show a list of the commits since `<the ref from step 3>` along with the default command for each one (`pick`).
6. Follow the instructions conveniently contained within the file to reorder the commits and squash them however you like. There are other commands you can choose as well.

   (If you don't make any changes and let `git rebase` run the file as-is, it will replay those exact commits in that order -- in other words, the same as before and nothing will have changed.)
7. Close the file. Git will proceed to execute the `todo` script.

   > *"Possibly after this there is some breakage- maybe some changes depended on those other changes in separate files and are now out of order"*

   This will show up as merge conflicts. The rebase process will stop so you can resolve those conflicts. Every time `rebase -i` stops for any reason, it provides helpful information on what you need to do and how to resume the script.

   If there are no conflicts, the script will proceed commit by commit without stopping.

   > #### You can easily abort any time you are having problems.
   >
   > If any conflict is giving you too much trouble or if you are having doubts, you can use `git rebase --abort` to abort the whole script and return you to exactly where you started. Thus there is no risk.
8. When it is done, if you did step 2, you can `git diff <orig branch> <tmp-branch-name>` to make sure no changes were lost. If all looks good, you can `git branch -f <orig branch> <tmp-branch-name>` to point your original branch at the new commit history.

---

`git rebase -i` is pretty much my favorite git command. It i worth becoming an expert in it. `git help rebase` is a good place to start -- read the parts about `-interactive` rebases. Also there are probably lots of blog posts on it.

Comment: I'm familiar with `git rebase -i` and using it extensively led to this question, perhaps I need to reword to make that more clear but it is about automation of the parts you have as manual steps.

Comment: "This will show up as merge conflicts."

I should be more clear, the breakage I'm somewhat worried about is at the run time system level not at the git text conflict level.  If I'm not doing CI that covers those cases for every commit within a PR (not just the tip) they would go unnoticed given the squash strategy outlined in the question.

Comment: Sure i understand. So did you try this, and did it work for you? As I said above, `git rebase -i` is a powerful tool that most people should master.